# How to check if a stream from an SmbFile is ready to be read?

Tags: java, java-io, jcifs

what would be the equivalent of this code:

```
    FileReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        reader = new FileReader( file);
        return reader.ready();
    }
    catch( IOException ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

For `SmbFile` ? I tried that:

```
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        SmbFileInputStream fstream = new SmbFileInputStream( file);
        reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( fstream));
        return reader.ready();
    }
    catch( IOException ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

but then I always get "false" as result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation looks that there's no guarantee that this flag assure it cannot be read, [Note that returning false does not guarantee that the next read will block.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#ready--)

You can try this way to avoid null values,

```
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

You can look at this post too, [bufferedreader-not-stating-ready-when-it-should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760044/bufferedreader-not-stating-ready-when-it-should)

Hope this helps